# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream oblivious of 404 response and allows writing

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

While troubleshooting a problem in HTTP Post to a RequestStream, i found that the upload of 4-16gb of data was occurring nearly instantaneously only for the web server to report i hadn't written ContentLength to the stream.

During troubleshooting i noticed in wireshark i was getting a fin/ack directly after the request for the response stream but i couldn't validate this socket closing within the response stream.

When i finally got to look into the SSL packets, it was a 404 being returned from the webserver but the stream was completely ignorant to this error.

[wireshark output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZSo2.png)

```
HttpWebRequest oWebrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oUri);
oWebrequest.ContentType = "application/x-vnd.vmware-streamVmdk";
oWebrequest.Method = Method.POST.ToString();
oWebrequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
//oWebrequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
oWebrequest.ReadWriteTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds;
oWebrequest.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds;
oWebrequest.SendChunked = false;
oWebrequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
        (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
        {
        return true;
        };
oWebrequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 1024;
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
oWebrequest.ContentLength = fi.Length;
Stream RequestStream = oWebrequest.GetRequestStream();
byte[] buffer = new Byte[(uint)Math.Min(1 * 1024, fi.Length)];
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, buffer.Length, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
{
    Int64 uploaded_bytes = 0;
    int chunk_size;
    double progress;
    try
    {
        double currentProgress = 0;
        // Stream the file in chunks
        while ((chunk_size = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
        RequestStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)chunk_size);
        RequestStream.Flush();
}
```

i would have expected at the requeststream write or flush for an exception to be thrown to suggest there may be a problem, but no such findings.

So i was wondering, is there a better, safer way to upload a large file with progress with handling for webserver errors such as 404? it seems largely wasteful to pump the contents of the filestream to a dead RequestStream before being told there is a problem.

Comment: The 404 error response came back in 0.01 seconds.  Nothing got uploaded.  You got a response back so there was no exception.  The server did not like the request.  It could not find the file.  Does the code run using Post Man or some other tool?  Use Sniffer and compare http header for good and bad results.  I guess use looked at the TCP packets and found the connection was closed [FIN].  So the failure was the SSL credentials?  The 404 not found was due to server ignoring request because of the SSL security failing.

Comment: yeah it didnt even try to upload, but in the app it continues to write  and flush until it gets to the end of the filestream unknowing of the 404 below it. The server issue is a bug and I'm hoping to get that resolved, but being aware of the 404 is what i would like to get to.

Comment: 404 would be the response status code.

Comment: What is `Method.POST`? Is it something like `HttpMethod.Post`? -- With `WebRequest`, you always need a `try/catch` block and catch `WebException`. It throws for any `StatusCode > 399`. -- You need to add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. IMO, remove `oWebrequest.SendChunked = false;` (it's the default and you never hard-code it anyway, unless you're trying to force it; it doesn't happen). The send buffer is too small.